# Please help me with my DONUT TUTORIAL!

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

I'm following the donut tutorial as “hello world” to Blender.

[image]

I used geometry nodes to built random sprinkles, now, I am facing a problem.

My sprinkles are overlapping each others. How can I make them detect each other and perfectly sit on top each other?

Comment: Use a Poisson distribution in the distribute node. It lets you setup a minimal distance between each point

Comment: Ya i know. But when i higher the minimal distance, the sprinkles started to become lesser. I want many sprinkles placing on top each others instead of intersecting each others.

Comment: Could you add a diagram of what you want to achieve ? Your comment is a little bit contradictory to me :)

Comment: As you said, you're using this as "hello world" to Blender. The "hello world" version is a simple distribution where you either use _Poisson Disk_ or have to accept that they overlap. Calculating overlap and respecting the geometry of randomly distributed instances is much more complex and definitely not "hello world". That's why it's not taught in Andrew's donut tutorial. I would go on watching more _Geometry Nodes_ tutorials about more complex things to learn more how that works. Unfortunately I cannot recommend any videos right now which deal exactly with that problem.

Comment: Haha Gordon, you surely got the point there. But as a beginner, I really felt frustrated and helpless with no knowledge to achieve my goal......

Comment: @Henly That's why you probably should not stop after the donut tutorial and go on doing more advanced tutorials ;)

Comment: For sure ! Thank you both Gordon and Gorgious.

Comment: Anyone who has the solution, pls do let me know. Love from blender community.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)